# Does internal energy increase or decrease during a combustion reaction?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, combustion

Combustion has negative enthalpy, and negative q. By dU = q + w (assume constant pressure), dU should be negative.

However, U is a function of T, yet the gas gets hotter after combustion.

Is dU positive or negative? What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Microscopically internal energy is the sum of the kinetic energy and potential energy of the constituent particles. In the combustion process the chemical potential energy decreases more than the kinetic energy increases.

Answer (score 2):

Combustion is a chemical reaction. The gas (let's say hydrogen) becomes a *different kind of gas* (in this case, water vapor). The fact that water vapor has a lower chemical energy than hydrogen is what makes for the negative change in internal energy.

Comment: Combustion causes temperature to rise, and with U(T), doesn’t that make internal energy of products higher?

Comment: @Kiewriosity No, again, the chemical potential energy goes way down and that completely dwarfs any increase in thermal energy due to heating. You seem to be applying some formula like $U=\alpha k T$ well outside its domain of validity.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the enthalpy decreases during a combustion reaction means that, to arrive at a final state where the temperature of the products is the same as the temperature that the reactants had been before reaction, heat had to be removed.  If the reaction were carried out adiabatically in a closed container, Q and W would both be zero, so $\Delta U$ would be zero also, even though the temperature of the products was higher than the original temperature of the reactants.  Here what happens is that the decrease in internal energy from converting reactants to products is exactly balanced by the increase in internal energy as a result of the increase in the sensible heat of the products.